# The controller for path '/Home' was not found or does not implement IController

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've searched the internet high and low and checked all previously answered questions with the same title and I cannot figure this one out.

I return **RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")** from the action method in my authentication controller and then receive the following exception:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The controller for path '/Home' was not found or does not implement IController.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The controller for path '/Home' was not found or does not implement IController.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[HttpException (0x80004005): The controller for path '/Home' was not found or does not implement IController.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +683921
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +89
   Castle.Proxies.Invocations.IControllerFactory_CreateController.InvokeMethodOnTarget() +155
   Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed() +116
   Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.ExecutionTimer.Time(Action action) +85
   Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.AlternateMethod.NewImplementation(IAlternateMethodContext context) +186
   Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed() +604
   Castle.Proxies.IControllerFactoryProxy.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +193
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +305
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +87
   System.Web.Mvc.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap(Func`1 func) +41

[HttpException (0x80004005): Execution of the child request failed. Please examine the InnerException for more information.]
   System.Web.Mvc.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap(Func`1 func) +785832
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride) +3977
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage) +275
   System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm) +94
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.ActionHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, TextWriter textWriter) +700
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues) +123
   Panoptes.Ui.Web.Views.Home.Index.Execute() in c:\Dropbox\Energy Management System\Application\Panoptes\Panoptes.Ui.Web\obj\CodeGen\Views\Home\Index.cshtml:48
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +280
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +126
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +143
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +181
   RazorGenerator.Mvc.PrecompiledMvcView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +952
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +378
   Castle.Proxies.AsyncControllerActionInvokerProxy.InvokeActionResult_callback(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +21
   Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed() +116
   Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.ExecutionTimer.Time(Action action) +85
   Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.AlternateMethod.NewImplementation(IAlternateMethodContext context) +186
   Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed() +604
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17() +33
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +854172
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +854172
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +265
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +838644
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +65
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +51
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +51
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18034
```

The authentication controller looks as follows:

```
    public class AuthenticationController : Controller
{
    private ILogService _logService;
    private IEmailProvider _emailProvider;
    private IMembershipProvider _membershipProvider;
    private IAuthenticationProvider _authenicationProvider;

    public AuthenticationController(ILogService logService, IEmailProvider emailProvider, IMembershipProvider membershipProvider, IAuthenticationProvider authenicationProvider)
    {
        _logService = logService;
        _emailProvider = emailProvider;
        _membershipProvider = membershipProvider;
        _authenicationProvider = authenicationProvider;
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    ////[OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByParam = "none")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateHttpAntiForgeryToken] 
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (_membershipProvider.ValidateUser(model.Username, model.Password))
            {
                _authenicationProvider.AuthenticateUser(model.Username);
                ////this.HttpContext.User = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(model.Username), null);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
                {
                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
                    {
                        return Redirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _logService.Log(new SecurityException(string.Format("Open redirect to {0} detected (Username {1})", returnUrl, model.Username)));
                        return View("Index", model);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, Resources.Controller.View.Authentication.Index.IncorrectUsernamePassword);
            }
        }

        return View("Index", model);
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateHttpAntiForgeryToken] 
    public ActionResult ForgotPassword(LoginModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValidField("Username"))
        {
            if (!_membershipProvider.EnablePasswordRetrieval)
            {
                throw new Exception(Resources.Controller.View.Authentication.Index.PasswordRetreivalNotAllowed);
            }

            IMembershipUser user = _membershipProvider.FindUsersByName(model.Username).FirstOrDefault();

            if (user != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    _emailProvider.Send(ConfigurationHelper.GetSmtpSettings().Smtp.From, user.EmailAddress, Resources.Global.PasswordRecoveryEmailSubject, user.GeneratePasswordRetreivalEmail());
                    ModelState.AddModelSuccess(Resources.Controller.View.Authentication.Index.PasswordSentViaEmail);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logService.Log(ex);
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, Resources.Controller.View.Authentication.Index.UnableToRetreivePassword);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, Resources.Controller.View.Authentication.Index.EmailAddressDoesNotExist);
            }
        }

        ViewBag.ShowForgottenPasswordForm = "true";

        return View("Index", model);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Logout()
    {
        _authenicationProvider.Logout();
        ModelState.AddModelInformation(Resources.Controller.View.Authentication.Index.Logout);
        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

My HomeController looks as follows:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IMembershipProvider _membershipProvider;
    private IAuthenticationProvider _authenticationProvider;

    public HomeController(IMembershipProvider membershipProvider, IAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider)
    {
        _membershipProvider = membershipProvider;
        _authenticationProvider = authenticationProvider;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_membershipProvider.GetCurrentUser());
    }
}
```

See below my RouteConfig:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Authentication", action = "Index" });
    }
}
```

RouteDebugger returns TRUE for the routes {controller}/{action} and {*catchall} and confirms the AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath as: ~/Home

I have debugged the code and I can successfully debug and step into the HomeController constructor and Index action method.  I have also been able to step into the "~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml" however it throws the exception at the line of code:

```
<span class="username">@Model.UserName</span>
```

Funnily enough, before I step into this code I can add "@Model.UserName" to my list of watches and I can see the object and its properties fine, but for some reason it throws an exception when stepping into or over this line of code.

If the debugger steps into the HomeController, the Index action method and the Index view, then why is it all of a sudden throwing the exception it can't find the HomeController for the path "~/Home"?

The captured fiddler data can be found at the following link: http://d-h.st/IqV

I have used Razor Generator to compile my views and I am also using Ninject.Mvc to resolve my controllers.  It's also worth mentioning I have cleared down and re-generated the compiled views and my project does not contain any registered areas.

Any idea's? this might be simple or an obvious one but I'm new to MVC and am reading/learning as I go.

Thanks

Comment: Could you show initialization of routes and your Home controller class?

Comment: Can you post code for HomeController?

Comment: Added the missing information into the question, hope this is ok.

Comment: Could you use Fiddler to get url that is when you RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

Comment: Hi, I've added the link to the NetworkData.xml from fiddler in the question, but for convenience it can be found here: http://d-h.st/IqV

Comment: oh ... my .... god.  What was the problem? see the following anchor tag in the HomeController Index view: 

<a href="@Html.Action("Log Out","Logout", "Authentication")"><i class="icon-key"></i> Log Out</a>

As you can see it's passing the wrong arguments and "Log Out" should be the action name, I correct to the following and it worked:

<a href="@Html.Action("Logout", "Authentication")"><i class="icon-key"></i> Log Out</a>

Nice of the framework to give me a meaningful error so I can diagnose the issue! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So people can see this question was answered here is why it was throwing the exception and how I fixed it:

The exception was being thrown because of the following line of code in the HomeController Index view:

```
<a href="@Html.Action("Log Out","Logout", "Authentication")"><i class="icon-key"></i> Log Out</a>
```

As you can see it's passing the wrong arguments and "Log Out" is being passed in as the  action name when infact this should be "Logout". I correct it to the following and it worked:

```
<a href="@Html.Action("Logout", "Authentication")"><i class="icon-key"></i> Log Out</a>
```

So if you're getting this exception and like me can't understand why then please make sure you check the rest of your code in your view to make sure it is correct.  In this instance the framework doesn't provide a meaning exception message and stacktrace.